# Searching a way for Platform Specific Implementations in .Net 6 console application

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0, maui

I’m going to create a cross platform console application specifically for Windows and Mac but I couldn’t find any straightforward way to place the **platform specific implementations**.

So far my understanding, there is a way to implement platform specific code separately by [using MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code). However, as I intended to do a console application (UI less application) thus I guess the MAUI is not a perfect solution (*I could be wrong*) .

Could anyone please suggest to me how to use platform specific code in the .Net 6 console app or is there any way to convert a MAUI application to a console application?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of something that you believe will need to be platform specific in a console application?

Comment: One way to start it of would be [SupportedOSPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.supportedosplatformattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute, You can annotate classes with this attribute and this will throw an exception if called on other platforms.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you can consider a custom feature where calculations depend on the OS or consider we are trying to get the screen orientations that need different API call depends on OS as per the [mentioned example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code).

Comment: But my point is, if you haven't identified a specific area where you need platform specific code, *maybe you don't need the facility to write platform specific code*, so searching for a solution for it now may be premature.

Comment: One way could be to use runtime check of `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(...)`. Another to compile to each platform individually and use #pragma to include code. It probably depend on what you want to do, ideally you would want to avoid platform specific code as much as possible.

Comment: It looks like .Net team hasn't yet created project type for cross-platform .net 6 development, using the new Minimal Hosting Model (as seen in ASP.Net and Maui). Once they do, this will make it easy to have a single project organized the way a Maui project is (separate folder for each platform's startup logic and platform-specific partial classes and other code). Until this is ready, not sure there is a better technique than code-sharing using symlink (on drive and in git repo). So VS sees a Mac console project and a Windows console project, but the "common" files can be shared.